# What is the root directory OR how do I set the directory in DotNetZip

Tags: c#, file-io, dotnetzip

where does DotNetZip get it's root directory for saving.  All the save examples don't show the directory.

My goal is to recurse a folder and subfolders.  In each folder I want to zip all the files into one zip and delete the source files.

```
    private void CopyFolder(string srcPath, string dstPath)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(dstPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dstPath);
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(srcPath);
        string msg;
        string zipFileName;
        using (ZipFile z = new ZipFile(Path.Combine(srcPath,String.Format("Archive{0:yyyyMMdd}.zip", DateTime.Now))))
        {
            z.ReadProgress += new EventHandler<ReadProgressEventArgs>(z_ReadProgress);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
                AddLog(String.Format("Adding {0}", file));
                z.AddFile(file);

            }
            //z.Save(Path.Combine(srcPath, String.Format("Archive{0:yyyyMMdd}.zip", DateTime.Now)));
            z.Save();
            if (deleteSource)
            {
                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    File.Delete(file);
                }
            }

            zipFileName = z.Name;
        }
        if (!compressOnly)
            File.Copy(Path.Combine(srcPath,zipFileName), Path.Combine(dstPath, Path.GetFileName(zipFileName)));
        string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath);
        foreach (string folder in folders)
        {
            string name = Path.GetFileName(folder);
            string dest = Path.Combine(dstPath, name);
            Console.WriteLine(ln);
            log.Add(ln);
            msg = String.Format("{3}{4}Start Copy: {0}{4}Directory: {1}{4}To: {2}", DateTime.Now.ToString("G"), name, dest, ln, Environment.NewLine);
            AddLog(msg);
            if (recurseFolders)
                CopyFolder(folder, dest);
            msg = String.Format("Copied Directory: {0}{4}To: {1}\nAt: {2}{3}", folder, dest, DateTime.Now.ToString("G"), Environment.NewLine);
            AddLog(msg);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a path relative to the [current working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), or an absolute path.  This is basically standard procedure for paths.

EDIT: The path you save to has nothing to do with directories inside the zip.  Either:

```
using(ZipFile f = new ZipFile("zip_dir/foo.zip"))
{
       f.AddFile("foo.txt");
       f.Save();
}
```

or

```
using(ZipFile f = new ZipFile())
{
        f.AddFile("foo.txt");
        f.Save("zip_dir/foo.zip");
}
```

does the correct thing, namely create a zip file at ./zip_dir/foo.zip containing a single foo.txt file.  Of course, you can create subdirectories in the zip, but it's a separate issue.

Comment: And how is this set?  With a static meathod from a class in System.File.IO?

Comment: You can use Directory.SetCurrentDirectory if you want to, and have the required permissions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory.aspx).  It isn't required, since you can always specify the path another way.

Answer (score 2):

A little late and maybe we're talking about two different versions, but it might still be of help to others.

You can specify where files are stored in archive by using the second argument to AddFile.
`@"\"` means all files will be stored in root.

```
z.AddFile(file,@"\");
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor you are using `ZipFile z = new ZipFile(...)` takes a path which is the location the zip file is saved.

Comment: that's true, and I have that implemented, but it creates sub-directories in the zip and I don't want that.